# Docker composer volumes on WSL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume, volumes

I'm trying to perform a trivial action: share folder between host and container.

But when I'm mounting some folders from host they appear empty in the container.

I've done following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  t1:
    image: ubuntu
    volumes:
      - /bin:/test
    command: '/bin/bash -c "/bin/ls /test"'
```

And after starting this I see some content, but it is really different from what I see if run `ls /bin` on host.

As I understand it shows the content of that MobbyLinuxVM from hyper-v, but that not what I want...

Is there any way to make volumes work in expected way from WSL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’ve found this: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1854 it shows how to use folder from windows fs (how to properly mount drive C to make it accessible) but not show how to access WSL fs.